# Android text view of screen

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a problem with my project I have a long text which goes off screen and I need a scrollview I fixed that however now my text goes off screen to the right it dosent stay all compact in anyone have any suggestions? I want my text to be in and fully visable as well as having a scroll since its a lot.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/abouthusky"
            android:id="@+id/abouthusky"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Here is the Fragment code:

```
public class Fragment_list_1 extends android.app.Fragment {
View rootview;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout_1, container, false);
    return rootview;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abouthusky"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/abouthusky"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:ellipsize="middle" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: did not work the text still goes off screen to the right.

Comment: still did not wortk sadly

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to your `TextView`:

```
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:maxLines="100"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

Comment: @edgaraxe, Try to remove `LinearLayout` around `TextView`. In my case `TextView` in `ScrollView` and it works fine

Comment: @edgaraxe and set `width` to `wrap_content`

Comment: @edgaraxe, Of course, this is not elegant solution, but may be you should just add `android:padding="10dp"`? It may give you a tempory solution

Answer (score 0):

Using a RelativeLayout with kind of complicated alignment of your TextView is not necessary in this case.
You should be fine by using a simple LinearLayout as a parent.

Also, it could be the scrollbar that overlaps your text on the right hand side.

So please try this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/abouthusky"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:id="@+id/abouthusky"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot?
Is this a layout for a Fragment or for an Activity ?

Comment: Could be the scrollbar, so please try my edited answer. Maybe you have to move the "android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"" to the LinearLayout or the ScrollView. Since i cant reproduce the error i cant check it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:orientation="vertical"` to your `LinearLayout`.